# User is not eligible for this purchase Android inApp

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am going through a problem while doing inapp android purchases. I have tried everything I can but it seems to be stuck on the error `user is not eligible to this purchase`. Please guide me through what i'm doing wrong. Below are the steps I followed

1. signed apk uploaded to play store
2. inapp product in published state
3. user is on test device
4. version code and version name are same as uploaded apk to store

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Not Yet, Still looking for it can you tell me exactly what u did ? may be i can help you.

Comment: Well, just followed steps in readme of in-app-billing-v03 example. I've changed the package name, signed and uploaded to Play. I've created "gas" SKU and got that error when terying to purchase it. Works fine with test.android.purchased but not with real products.

Comment: yeah, works with test id of mine too. have you received any two emails by google mentioning first transaction successful and then a sudden email one failure of it. This is because you may have your test account on hold or no credit in that. BTW, what is "gas" SKU ?

Comment: I have no credit card attached, however it should not be a problem. Play app should prompt user to add credit card. "gas" SKU in an example SKU of new market sample app. I have rebooted the device and now got "RPC:S-5:AEC-0" error.

Comment: I think I'll stick with API v2 for a while. There I haven't had those problems.

Comment: go ahead with your work and be in touch if u resolve the problem and i'll update u as well. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, several hours after uploading apk I finally can purchase items. So for your case I'd suggest to wait and try again.

Comment: Haven't upgraded to IABv3 but I'm seeing the same problem.  I can purchase items from one of my apps that is already live, but when I try with my app that is not published yet, I get "User is not eligible for this purchase" (same device/test account).  fwiw, it has been two days, the product has definitely permeated the system by now, and my test account does have valid CC details.

Comment: yeah, i'm still having this issue and not yet moved IABv3 latest and i'm using new look google play store as well. I see only reason not being shifted to IAV3. I've tried everything.

Answer (score 4):

This error comes when everything you done is perfect, you have used signed APK with the proper product id, but you have to note that the account that you are using might don't have proper **valid credit card details**.

So whenever you want to **buy any product even with test account**, that account should have **valid credit details**.

You have to specify test account in Edit profile of your publisher account

**Licensing & In-app Billing**

**Test Accounts** box

Comment: i have tried with credit enabled account too and also made it a test account as well. Still prompting the same issue.

Comment: You have created another gmail account and not your publisher account? And also your device should be logged in with the same test account

Comment: I have two publisher accounts. What i did is i made one publisher account having credit as a test account to the other official account where i uploaded my .apk and signed in to device with that test account. it didnt worked. Secondly, i used new account having no credit in that as a test account and signed in to the device, the same problem appears. again.

Comment: I'm having the same error, it's definitely not credit card information. I can make purchases with the test account, other iab test apps work. But this one is giving me the "user not eligible error".

Answer (score 1):

I thought I share mine too.

I have had the same issue with my test device. I have done all the stuff noted in many documents until by accident I tested it on different device with SIM card and everything was fine.

My test device doesnt have a SIM card and just Wireless Internet. So Google can't verify it. I can buy any app I want from the Google Play though.

My other test device is with different test account + it has a Proper SIM card with data plan.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: Very interesting. Indeed I test with my test account on my other Android Phone without SIM cart and I got this message. Did you success to test IAP on your Phone without sim card?

Answer (score 0):

Took me 2 days to find out that you not only have to create the app under console v2, but upload it under v2, too.

My problem was that, under v2, I could not upload anything (no pictures, no APK)... so I switched back to v1, and did all the uploads there.

(Just to note: v2 console doesn't tell you all the details on what is needed to have a 'draft' or publish the app. So I switched back and forth...)

So, after having all that "User not eligible" trouble, I finally decided to do the whole process again, and found out that with Google Chrome the upload doesn't work. :D

Finally, with Firefox the upload did work, and I never saw that error again ;)

Comment: Good to hear that, a little strange and interesting fact. Let me try this out and let you know the result. Thanks!

Comment: @QaiserButt so what have you found?

Comment: Actually, i have set it on hold and will get back to it later on. I will update my solution for sure soon i find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue for 2 days. Finally, I have discovered that there was a problem with  my credit card currency. I used Amex for my test account, and it didn't allow billing in Euros, only in dollars. The problem was solved when I used an european credit card.

The best is to try to purchase some existing stuff with your google play test account to be sure that the issue does not come from your account configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear what was my problem was that my test IAP purchase worked fine in my game but i couldn't purchase actual IAP game products.

Finally i found this worked having trying for 2 months. There were many things i tried and could be the possible reason seeing all this. But the important one that seems to me a lot problematic, i tried to purchase IAP products through american based credit card while sitting in pakistan. As many times i tried to purchase, i first get a purchase successful email and then sudden after that i receive a cancellation of the purchase email from google. So i went to try this purchase by my friend in USA and it worked.

Last thing, i want to mention is this could not be the only reason behind seeing these alerts as i couldn't remember all stuff that i gone through to make this work.

Thanks every one for all the efforts!

Answer (score 0):

There are only two reasons for this error: 
1> Signed in account in Play Store App doesn't not have testing permission . Add this account to test accounts on Google play

2> Publisher can't buy their own products . In-Apps or even paid apps

Comment: It’s great you shared your experience, but there are certainly more than two reasons for this error, as seen above.