# Android in app billing version 3 “User is not eligible for this purchase”

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing InApp Billing V3 in our Apk.

1. Create a signed APK
2. Upload using Developer Console
3. Add a Managed In-App product.
4. Make the In-App product active, but don't publish the app.
5. Modify the public key in the apk with the one from developer console
6. Install the apk on a phone and try to perform InApp Purchasing.

I'm using a test account on the phone with a different user & credit card to the main merchant account. I've verified that the Public Key in the app is correct.

I've checked using the "android.purchased" etc. strings and these all work fine.

I've seen this issue mentioned various times, the solutions appear to be to wait a while and possibly to delete the APK and reload it using the OLD developer console.

Amongst other pages I've tried what's mentioned in:

- [User is not eligible for this purchase Android inApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820674/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-android-inapp)
- [User is not eligible for this purchase - in app billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747736/user-is-not-eligible-for-this-purchase-in-app-billing)

I did get this working at one point, and managed to purchase the item. 
Unfortunately, I had no idea what exactly I'd done to suddenly get this to work, and wanted to document the steps required for future use (I suspect that it may have been a mixture of timing and changing things in the Developer Console).
So I restarted the process with a new package name and now all I get is "User is not eligible to purchase this item".

There's clearly a difference between the Google documentation, and the real world with regards to InApp Purchase, but whatever I don it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: At least for me using old Dev Console to upload an APK was a solution.

Comment: Hi Stipa, Can you tell me a bit more about how you got this to work.

Comment: I've switched to old dev console and uploaded APK from there.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a series of steps which work. Tried this twice today and both times IAB worked after a few hours. The steps I followed:

- Create a signed build and upload to Google Store – using the OLD Developer Console view. Fill in all the App details in the old console.
- Switch to New Developer Console
- Upload the APK, built with the new Public Key – since the old upload will not set IAB to supported.
- Add a Managed InApp Product and Activate it
- Wait a while. This could be a few hours according to some web pages. In my test this took around 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two reasons for this error: 1> Signed in account in Play Store App doesn't not have testing permission . Add this account to test accounts on Google play

2> Publisher can't buy their own products . In-Apps or even paid apps